# gradle unable to resolve espresso intents, runner, rules and core

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.0'
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'jsr305'
    })
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.0',{
        exclude module: 'jsr305'
    })
```

I have added the above to my app's `build.gradle`. But android studio gives the error saying that it cannot resolve the above dependencies. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

These will now be under the Google's repository, so in order to add them in, you will need to change the `repositories` on your build.gradle to the following:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    // Add this if you use Gradle 4.0+
    google()
    // Add this if you use Gradle < 4.0
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
```

And once you've added Google in, you should be able to download and use those dependencies.

Hope this helps you

Comment: What version of Gradle are you on?

Comment: I am on gradle 3.3

Comment: and what do you have for `com.android.tools.build:gradle:` in your project level build.gradle? I'm using 2.3.3. Latest here https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle

Comment: @Ashwin You should update to 4.0, or use `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }`

Comment: Did this help you out @Ashwin?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version 26 of support libraries and the new test support libraries make sure that the `repositories` section includes a maven section with the "https://maven.google.com" endpoint.

```
repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
```